# Creating a 2D array of tuples from 2 1D array

Tags: python

I have 1 list and i want to create a 2D array of all possible tuples.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]

output = [[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],
          [(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)],
          [(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]]
```

whats the easiest/quickest way to do this?

Comment: It is important to demonstrate that you are *also* working to solve your question. The best way I have found to do that is to include the text version of the code you have tried so far. Check out `itertools.product()` to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[[(x, y) for y in list1] for x in list1]
```